# Keys are not being added to my json object while looping through it

Tags: javascript, json

This is driving me crazy. I have this json object:

```
var category_images = {
  "blah": [
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    }
  ],
  "blah2": [
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    }
  ]
}
```

And I'm trying to add a new property to each inner json object like this:

```
for(var property in category_images){
    for (var i = 0; i < property.length; i++) {
        category_images[property]["new_property"] = "HI";
    }
}
```

and then save it like this:

`fs.writeFileSync('test.json', JSON.stringify(category_images, null, 4));`

But nothing is updated when i load the file... What am i doing wrong

Comment: have you tried logging the category_images object, to check if that's actually the issue, it could be the write failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out finally. Two issues:

1. My inner loop was wrong. The condition needs to be `i < category_images[property].length`
2. I was indexing into my subarrays incorrectly. Should've been doing this `category_images[property][i]["src_compressed"] = "HI";`

Final result:

```
for(var property in category_images){
    console.log(category_images[property].length);
    for (var i = 0; i < category_images[property].length; i++) {
        category_images[property][i]["src_compressed"] = "HI";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var category_images = {
  "blah": [
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    }
  ],
  "blah2": [
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    },
    {
      "src": "...",
      "title": "...",
      "alt": "..."
    }
  ]
}

Object.keys(category_images).forEach((key)=>{
    category_images[key] = category_images[key].map((item)=>{ return {...item, new_property: "HI"} })
})

console.log(category_images)
```